# Session state being reset on IE

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am having some issues using a session state in a website. Each postback empties the session state. When i test the website from my desktop, it functions normally.
When I use the deployed website, the session state is lost after each postback.

I have tried enabling the session state at application level and at page level

Application (web.config):

```
<system.web>
  <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20"></sessionState>
</system.web>
```

Page level (aspx page)

```
<%@ Page EnableSessionState="True" %>
```

Neither seemed to work. I also checked in IIS if the sessionstate was enabled and it was. This is all i know which could enable or disable the session state. Another detail of the problem is, that when the pages are opened using the ip address, the session state works fine. When i open the pages using the dns name, the session state fails to work. The event viewer also foes not show the session being reset each time.

I am using IE 10. Again on another browser (chrome) it works fine, but our client uses IE.

Does anyone have an idea where this problem could be coming from? I can use the viewstate instead and it works fine, but I prefer to use the sessionstate as it's more accessible throughout the project.

Comment: Can you confirm that IE is sending  the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie in the postback request? e.g using Fiddler?

Comment: No this is not sent with the request. The message 'this request did not send any cookie data.' Is the session data stored in a form of a cookie at the client side?

Comment: The cookie stores the session identifier. The data is stored on the server (either in the IIS process memory, as you have configured), or the State service / SQL Server (out of process). Is your IE configured to permit session cookies?

Comment: It is. When i open the page using the ip address the session cookie is sent properly. when open it using the dns name, the session cookie does not appear to be sent.

Comment: Maybe there's some other group policy or something in effect. Can you enable cookies for that domain under Internet Options-> Privacy->Sites?

Comment: I checked and the site was in the trusted site, cookies are accepted. I turned off all protection and tried again with the same results.